# Getting error sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) invalid dsn: invalid connection option "pool_pre_ping" in postgres insert

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have declared my connection function as below..

```
def create_psql_engine(db):
#conn_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://myuser:******@someserver:port/somedb"
conn_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (
    db.get('user'),
    db.get('password'),
    db.get('host'),
    db.get('port'),
    db.get('dbname')
)
conn_args = {
    "sslmode": db.get('sslmode'),
    "sslcompression": db.get('sslcompression'),
    "sslrootcert": db.get('sslrootcert'),
    "sslcert": db.get('sslcert'),
    "sslkey": db.get('sslkey'),
    "pool_pre_ping": True,
    "pool_recycle": 300
}
try:
    engine = create_engine(conn_string, connect_args=conn_args)
    logging.info("sqlalchemy Engine to database created using psycopg2... ")
    return engine
except psycopg2.Error as error:
    logging.error(error)
```

And in my program I am connecting as below.

```
    # Create PostgreSQL Engine
    self.engine = abc.create_psql_engine(dbParam)
    print('PSQL Engine Created to Table : {}'.format(self.tableName))
```

Then I use a pandas to_sql for inserting into DB

```
df.to_sql(self.table,self.engine,schema='abc',index=False,if_exists='append',chunksize=100)
```

It was working all this while with out the below 2 options.

```
"pool_pre_ping": True,
"pool_recycle": 300
```

But I was gettin connection interruption when handling large volume. And which is the reason I am trying out a solution with these 2 parameters.

However, I get this error , when I tried. Any clue what I am doing wrong.

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) invalid dsn: invalid connection option "pool_pre_ping"
```

Complete error log as below..

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
     return fn()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 307, in connect
     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 767, in _checkout
     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 425, in checkout
     rec = pool._do_get()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
     self._dec_overflow()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
     with_traceback=exc_tb,
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
     raise exception
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
     return self._create_connection()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 368, in __init__
     self.__connect()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 611, in __connect
     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
     with_traceback=exc_tb,
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
     raise exception
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
     connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 175, in make_dsn
     parse_dsn(dsn)
 psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "pool_pre_ping"


 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/apps/python/loadtoPostgreSQL.py", line 275, in <module>
     MX123D.processFiles(jobIdentifier)
   File "/opt/apps/python/loadtoPostgreSQL.py", line 246, in processFiles
     df.to_sql(self.table,self.engine,schema='abc',index=False,if_exists='append',chunksize=100)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2615, in to_sql
     method=method,
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 598, in to_sql
     method=method,
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1393, in to_sql
     table.create()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 721, in create
     if self.exists():
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 708, in exists
     return self.pd_sql.has_table(self.name, self.schema)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1431, in has_table
     self.connectable.dialect.has_table, name, schema or self.meta.schema
   File "<string>", line 2, in run_callable
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 390, in warned
     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3074, in run_callable
     with self.connect() as conn:
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3166, in connect
     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
     else engine.raw_connection()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3245, in raw_connection
     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3216, in _wrap_pool_connect
     e, dialect, self
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2070, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
     sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_infoÝ2¨, from_=e
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
     raise exception
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
     return fn()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 307, in connect
     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 767, in _checkout
     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 425, in checkout
     rec = pool._do_get()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
     self._dec_overflow()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
     with_traceback=exc_tb,
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
     raise exception
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
     return self._create_connection()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 368, in __init__
     self.__connect()
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 611, in __connect
     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
     with_traceback=exc_tb,
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
     raise exception
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
     connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 175, in make_dsn
     parse_dsn(dsn)
 sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) invalid dsn: invalid connection option "pool_pre_ping"

 (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Comment: The error states that `pool_pre_ping` doesn't seem to be a valid parameter, so deleting it should make the code work again

Comment: But as per sqlalchemy documentation it is a valid parameter https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html  And I would like to use it to solve my connection break issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found the issue.Sharing here so that it can help some one.
Issue was that the parameters were given in wrong place :-)
It should be given as below.

```
engine = create_engine(conn_string, connect_args=conn_args,pool_pre_ping=True,pool_recycle=300)
```